# How to validate and compare the database records using RestAssured Automation Cucumber(Feature file)

Tags: java, sql, cucumber, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How to validate and compare the database records using RestAssured Automation Cucumber-Feature file by using parameterization. I want the tableName, columns and condition to be passed through the feature file and parameterize it. Is there a better way to do it, please suggest.

I want the SQL query parameters to be passed through the Scenario file. In the feature file, I am passing tablename=apidb_connection_user through the Cucumber step. column= "userId" and condition= "userid = '798874745' "

**Feature File:**

```
       Scenario: Validate Login
       And API response matches with the database apidb_connection_user table
       | userId | userid = '798874745' |
```

**APICommonSteps.java**

```
     @And("API response matches with the database <tablename> table")
     public void verifyDatabaseDetails(String tableName, DataTable data) throws SQLException {
     apiUtil.verifyDatabaseDetails(tableName, new HashMap<>(data.asMap()));
      }
```

**APIUtil.java:**

```
      public void verifyDatabaseDetails(String tableName, Map<String,String> data) throws SQLException {

      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      String sqlQuery = "Select" + column + " from " + tableName +"where" + condition;
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

      String databaseJson = String.valueOf(convertResultSetToJson(resultSet));
      String apiResponseJson = response.getBody().asString();

      softAssert.assertEquals(databaseJson, apiResponseJson, String.valueOf(true));
      
      resultSet.close();
      statement.close();
      connection.close();
     }

     private static JsonArray convertResultSetToJson(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
     JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

     while (resultSet.next()) {
     int totalColumns = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
     JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

     for (int i = 1; i <= totalColumns; i++) {
     String columnName = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
     String columnValue = resultSet.getString(i);
     jsonObject.addProperty(columnName, columnValue);
     }

     jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
     }

     return jsonArray;
 }
```